# Why is $\text{Funct}(X, Y) \subseteq \mathcal P (X \times Y)$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, definition

I searched for "set of all functions power set" but didn't find anything that looked relevant.

**Background:**

I am struggling to understand this paragraph from page 21 of *Analysis I* by Amann and Escher.

> [image]

The Remark cited is shown below.

> [image]

**Questions and comments:**

I don't understand why the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$ (i.e. $\text{Funct}(X, Y)$) is a subset of the set of all subsets of $X \times Y$ (i.e. $\mathcal P(X \times Y)$). It says in the Remark that a function from $X$ to $Y$ is a an ordered triple $(X, G, Y)$ meeting certain conditions. Doesn't that mean the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$ should be the set of all those ordered triples?

I'm also struggling to understand the part explaining that $X^n$ is the set of all functions from $\{ 1, 2, \dots, n \}$ to $X$. To me, the $n$-fold Cartesian product of $X$ is all the ordered $n$-tuples you get by selecting any $x \in X$ for each of the $n$ positions in the $n$-tuple. A function from $\{ 1, 2, \dots, n \}$ to $X$ would have as its image just a single $n$-tuple $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$, right? I guess if you identify each $n$-tuple with a function, then the set of all $n$-tuples is the set of all functions?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book’s treatment is sloppy. By their definition in **Remark** $\bf{3.1}$ a function from $X$ to $Y$ is **not** in fact a subset of $X\times Y$, despite what they say in their definition of $\operatorname{Funct}(X,Y)$. In that definition they’re actually talking about the set $G$ of ordered pairs, not the ordered triple $\langle X,G,Y\rangle$. The notation $\operatorname{Funct}(X,Y)$ identifies the domain and codomain of the functions in question, so there’s no loss of information in taking it to be the set of $G$s, but what they said is simply false.

$X^n$ can be defined as $\operatorname{Funct}(\{1,\ldots,n\},X)$, or it can be defined as the set of $n$-tuples of elements of $X$. These are formally distinct objects, but there is a natural bijection between them, so we normally just think of them as the same thing and use whichever representation is more convenient at the time.

Answer (score 2):

My own view (and one that's pretty important in much of computer science) is that a function, like Gaul, is divided in three parts: $f = (D, C, R)$, where $R$ is a subset of $D \times C$ with certain properties to make it "function like". $R$ is what the author of your text would call the "graph" of the function. $D$ and $C$ are called (by some) the domain and codomain.

So reading the definition carefully, as you did, shows that the set of all functions *isn't* actually a subset of $P(X \times Y)$, but instead,

$$Funct(X, Y) \subset \{X\} \times \{Y\} \times P(X \times Y).$$

On the other hand, there's a function that I'll call $\pi_3$ (for "projection on the third component") that sends $f = (D, C, R)$ to $R$, which maps $Funct(X, Y)$ to $P(X \times Y)$, and the author is hiding this in the description (alas).

In short: your understanding is fine; the author is being glib.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify a function $$f:X\rightarrow Y$$

with the set

$$\operatorname{graph}(f):=\{(x,f(x)):x\in X\}$$

which is a subset of $$X\times Y$$

Therefore the set $\operatorname{Funct}(X,Y)$ is a set of sets:

$$\operatorname{Funct}(X,Y)=\{f:X\rightarrow Y\}=\Big\{\{(x,f(x)):x\in X\}:f\text{ is a function}\Big\}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X\times Y)$$

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, it's really the set of all graphs, i.e. the $G$'s in the definition, that is a subset of $\mathcal P(X \times Y)$? It's not the functions themselves, but their graphs?

Comment: A function is formally defined via its graph. Therefore it is not something different, but just the definition of a function that is being used here.

Comment: Yes, the union of the graphs is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X\times Y)$, since any graph of a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a subset of $X\times Y$.